# How to secure password in code c# email client

Tags: c#, security, email, passwords, client

I am building a website for my brother's company. The most important element on the website is the mail function.  It is important that visitors can send emails to my brother using that system. So I used this code:

```
message.From = new MailAddress("someemail@somedomain.com");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("emailaddress"));
message.CC.Add(new MailAddress("emailaddress"));
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailaddress","password");
client.Send(message);
```

The code is working fine, but there is one problem: I need to fill in my password and I don't want to do that.  Is there a way to use something like MD5 hashes (or some other sort of encryption) or something else to secure my password?

Answer (score 6):

SMTP (protocol underlying email) requires that the password be provided in plain text.

You are already securing the communication channel, which should prevent interception of the email password on the wire.

You can place the password itself into an [encrypted element of web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to protect it at rest.

Finally, consider an account used *only* for this purpose.  Forward email from that account to your brother's account.  If the password is compromised, delete the account and create a new forwarding account.

Comment: Thanks for this information, and yes I already had in mind to use an account only used for sending emails to my brother.

Comment: @EricJ .NET 4 version of [`NetworkCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783746%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has a constructor that takes a [`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for password - are you saying that this can't be used with SMTPClient if it requires a plain text password? (I've not tried it, I'm just interested)

Comment: @Bridge: NetworkCredential is for "credentials in password-based authentication schemes such as basic, digest, NTLM, and Kerberos."  I'm not sure whether it works with SMTPClient or not, but at the end of the day, plain text will go over the (hopefully SSS-secured) wire, just as plain text would ultimately go over the wire for basic web authentication (which I know that NetworkCredential supports).  SecureString provides the added benefit that the string doesn't linger in system memory after use, but rather is actively overwritten.  That can help minimize exposure if the server is hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Details for the `System.Net` smtp email objects can be set in the app.config or web.config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k(v=vs.90).aspx

IF you set your password in the config file you can then encrypt that section to prevent cursory reading of your password. But ultimately the password needs to be provided as a string.