# What type of authentication is System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient using when sending emails?

Tags: c#, .net, email

Hopefully this question makes sense. I have some C# code that sends an email message given the username, password, and domain. How do I know what type of authentication it's using?

When I looked at the MSDN page for SmtpClient.Credentials Property it said that if you use basic authentication then credentials are sent over as plain text. Is the below code using basic authentication? MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(); 
MailAddress fromEmail = new MailAddress("from@yourdomain.com"); 

smtpClient.Host = "mail.mydomain.com";
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = cred;

message.From = fromEmail;
message.Subject = "my subject";

message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "hello world!";
message.To.Add("toEmail@anything.com"); 

smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: From what I can see, SmtpClient requires that the password requires being passed as plain text. But the recommendation is to store your Smtp settings in a web.config or app.config file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359445/how-to-secure-password-in-code-c-sharp-email-client. I'd say it's basic authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Typically `SmtpClient` will alway pick the "best" available authentication method (the SMTP server will tell the in the answer to the `EHLO` command). So we can't really answer without knowing what the server actually supports.

`SmtpClient` can choose from following methods: Negotiate, NTLM, Digest and Login

Here's some interesting reading about how to force `SmtpClient` to use a specific authentication method (slightly hack-ish btw.): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2008/04/16/hacking-system-net-mail-smtpclient.aspx

Comment: Pretty helpful, but I don't see how the EHLO command that the client sends to the server returns the "best" available authentication method. According to my google search results, the EHLO command just requests that the server send back a list of valid extend ESMTP commands, and not necessarily a list of authentication methods. However, EHLO does return "AUTH" in its list, letting the client know that they can use this command for authentication, provided that the client provides a username, password, and authentication mechanism. Almost there, just need to fill in this last detail.

Comment: References for my previous comment: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference.htm , http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference-auth.htm

Comment: Well, I didn't say it exactly that way. The server's response to EHLO contains a list of available authentication methods (See RFC 4954 P3: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4954#page-3). I wrote that `SmtpClient` will pick the "best" one out of that list.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. Thank for the info.

Answer (score 1):

This method will use basic authentification and will send the code via unsecure channel. This is because:

> The [`SmtpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class only supports the SMTP Service Extension for Secure SMTP over Transport Layer Security as defined in RFC 3207. **In this mode, the SMTP session begins on an unencrypted channel**, then a STARTTLS command is issued by the client to the server to switch to secure communication using SSL. See RFC 3207 published by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) for more information.

You can use the SSL for such situations:

> The `EnableSsl` property specifies whether SSL is used to access the specified SMTP mail server.

Also please note that

> You can use [ClientCertificates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.clientcertificates.aspx) to specify which client certificates should be used to establish the SSL connection. The [ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) allows you to reject the certificate provided by the SMTP server. The [SecurityProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol.aspx) property allows you to specify the version of the SSL protocol to use.

Comment: I agree on the point that the communication will be cleartext if not enabling SSL, but generally speaking the authentication still could be (more or less) secure if the password isn't sent in the message (that's what the question was about) if another method is chosen (as Negociate, NTLM or Digest)